# Delete AlarmManager Alarm ONLY for a Deleted Alarm

Tags: android, android-alarms

My app will have several alarms set simultaneously. Unfortunately, each alarm is being set with the same PendingIntent object. Here's the code I'm using to set the alarm:

```
//Use AlarmManager to trigger the notification/alarm.
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

//PendingIntent to launch activity when the alarm triggers.                    
Intent i = new Intent("com.testapp.DisplayNotification");

//Assign the reminder's primary key as the notification ID.
i.putExtra("Reminder_Name", editRemindMeTo.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("Reminder_Primary_Key", reminderPrimaryKey);

PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
getBaseContext(), 0, i, 0);               

//Set the alarm to trigger.
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
c.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);
```

I know that I can delete an alarm by using the following code:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 

Intent i = new Intent(context, MyPendingIntentService.class);
PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);

alarmManager.cancel(displyIntent);
```

However, using this code will delete ALL my alarms (correct me if I'm wrong here). Is there a way to delete *just* the alarm that a user has deleted from the database? The alarm should be deleted from my app right after the user deletes an alarm entry in my app's database. I'm guessing that using different PendingIntent names would be the way to go, but I have no idea how to do this for each new alarm that a user creates. Thoughts on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the same problem i faced here previously... 
So the solution is to pass unique pending intent to the alarm service.. So here i how it can be done

> PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, **(int) alarm_id**, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

here in the pending intent i have passed unique request id to the pending intent. Which you have to remember while cancelling  the alarm. 
So in my case what i have done to generate the unique id is put it in the database i have retrieved the id of the tables row and passed to the pending Intent.
So if you want to cancel the particular alarm you have to remember the same request id of the pending intent with the use of the same table entry...

I am sure it will work..

Comment: what do I pass as "intent" here ? Im deleting the alarms from absolutely different place in the app than the place Im setting them, so I have no intent here whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

Use a different `requestCode` when registering each alarm. This is the second parameter of `PendingIntent.getActivity/Service()`.

Comment: Hmmm, I remember reading somewhere that AlarmManager doesn't care about the requestCode and just uses the PendingIntent to determine which alarm to delete... was I given false information about that?

Comment: The documentation says `requestCode` is unused, but it is actually checked when comparing `PendingIntent`s.

Comment: Alrite, thank you! I'll give it a try and get back to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

From the Android Documentation, cancel() will cancel all alarms with same pendingIntent. So the only way out is to create different pendingIntents. OR you could resort to scheduling repeating alarms as well, in this way you could use the same pendingIntents.

Comment: I would try repeating alarms, but I'm already using that for a different functionality in my app. Do you have an idea on how to create new pendingIntents for each alarm? I tried to generate a random, non-repeating string, setting it to a variable, and then setting the variable as the pendingIntent name, but Java got confused between the variable reference and the pendingIntent object reference. How do I generate different pendingIntent names when my alarms have to go through the same lines of code? Thanks again!